# does returning from a thread release the resources?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have set of IO tasks (serial port communication) to do which I am pushing into a queue. Then there is a timer that checks this queue on each tick and if it is not empty, pops one task and runs it on a thread.

The problem is that when the second task tries to initiate using serial port communication, it causes a runtime error stating that the resources are being used by another thread. Which basically means the first thread has not released the access to the serial port.

Do I have to manually terminate the thread or release the resources of that thread, or when the task on the threads finishes, it automatically release all the resources it used (e.g. the access to the serial port)?

Here us the sudo code of the timer:

```
myFunctionThread()
{
    while ( q.Count != 0)
     doSomeTask(deQueue(q));
}
```

In the debug window it is showing that the thread is still alive even after doing all the operations.

Comment: Can you add sample code so we understand better what you want to do?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, are you asking why your terminated thread isn't doing any work?

Comment: Maybe you should just use the ThreadPool-queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the problem is that when i put a new task in the queue the thread does not begin to pop from the queue

Because it is terminated. If the thread is terminated when you push items, you must create a new one. Terminated means "done, from the OS point of view". It will not restart. Happens when you let the function in the thread "run out" - the return from the jump in method will terminate the thread.

Generally, I Would not work with threads here - I would work with tasks and queue a task whenever I push an item into the queue and there is no task already scheduled. A little "HasTask" bool with some locking and you are set.

What happens is that you have a programming error, show no code and do not think about edge cases in your logic. So the thread pulling items ends, you push something into the queue and - well.... I suggest you open a new question that has (a) a relevant title and (b) shows more work on your end to do debugging, in the form of enough code samples to walk you through the problem. This answer here is as good as you can get with the question you asked.

Comment: @Majidkhalili Can you explain me why a task marked as long running is not suitable for IO? Hint: it is not. And obviously it is not alive when it is shown as terminated. Your thread handling is broken, that is it. Simple like that. Fix it, or open a correct question with CODE so that we can help you.

Comment: @Majidkhalili Downvotes mean that the question has something wrong with it. Your question isn't clear, and to top that you're being rude to those who are trying to help.